# How to export notebook in PDF with long formulas in traditional format?

Tags: export, notebooks, stylesheet, pdf-format

I am trying to export notebook in PDF but these formulas below always automatically converts to raw input form such as $a/b$ instead of $\frac{a}{b}$. So it doesn't look nice.
There are many other fractions but all are OK except these long fractions. 
I have tried a lot of methods from old posts but haven't found anything similar and works for me.

I set these formulas with Bold and font 20. So how to export theses as  $\frac{a}{b}$ instead of $a/b$?

```
iL -> ((-1 + D1 + D2) Vin)/(2 ((-1 + D1 + D2)^2 R2 + 
       2 (-1 + D1 + D2) D3 R2 + D3^2 (R1 + R2))) ;
V1 -> -(((-1 + D1 + D2) D3 R1 Vin)/((-1 + D1 + D2)^2 R2 + 
       2 (-1 + D1 + D2) D3 R2 + D3^2 (R1 + R2)));
V2 -> ((-1 + D1 + D2) (-1 + D1 + D2 + 
       D3) R2 Vin)/((-1 + D1 + D2)^2 R2 + 2 (-1 + D1 + D2) D3 R2 + 
     D3^2 (R1 + R2));
VCF1 -> -(((-1 + D1 + D2 + D3) ((-1 + D1 + D2) R2 + 
         D3 (R1 + R2)) Vin)/((-1 + D1 + D2)^2 R2 + 
       2 (-1 + D1 + D2) D3 R2 + D3^2 (R1 + R2)));
VCF2 -> -((D3 ((-1 + D1 + D2) R2 + 
         D3 (R1 + R2)) Vin)/((-1 + D1 + D2)^2 R2 + 
       2 (-1 + D1 + D2) D3 R2 + D3^2 (R1 + R2)));
```

Comment: If you are writing using LaTeX, you can use TeXForm[put expression here], copy, paste in the TeX-document and when you convert it to pdf it has the form that you want.

Comment: I don't use LaTex in this notebook, just press `Ctrl + /` and fill out the formula.

Comment: Not in this formula. I meant if you want to use LaTeX to produce the pdf-file you want.

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea how to make those formulas above display `$\frac{a}{b}$` in PDF?

Comment: Give me a second. I will post an answer.

Comment: Are you using the "Save As" menu to export to PDF? If so, Input cells typically are formatted using InputForm. So, select the cell and convert it to StandardForm or TraditionalForm using the `Cell | Convert To` menu item or the equivalent short cut.

Comment: @CarlWoll: yes, I choose Save As. Well, I tried your method and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlWoll: I would like to remove the line "Printed by Wolfram Mathematica Student Edition" and "notebookname.nb" in exported PDF file. Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you take for example the first expression and put in Mathematica

```
TeXForm[((-1 + D1 + D2) Vin)/(2 ((-1 + D1 + D2)^2 R2 + 
      2 (-1 + D1 + D2) D3 R2 + D3^2 (R1 + R2)))]
```

The output is

\frac{\text{Vin} (\text{D1}+\text{D2}-1)}{2 \left(2 \text{D3} \text{R2}
   (\text{D1}+\text{D2}-1)+\text{R2} (\text{D1}+\text{D2}-1)^2+\text{D3}^2
   (\text{R1}+\text{R2})\right)}

And the pdf-file looks like [image: Result]

I hope that it is what you wanted.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks. But I only want to export the formula not including input like `TeXForm[]`. How to make the formula display as input?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that. If you copy the output of the TeXForm command, you will only export the formula, unless I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Well, I tried but PDF file the formula is clutter like output above and this link: https://imgur.com/KpmRHwC

Comment: And if you take that expression and compile it into a LaTeX file it should give you a nice looking fraction. I mean all the thing with the frac, etc etc

Comment: But I need to export PDF file because these formulas is in a big file.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. I type the formulas in Mathematica but when I export notebook in PDF using Save As, these formulas become raw input form in PDF file not the nice looking form.

Comment: No, I got it. This is why I suggested the particular command. It's just a matter of taking EACH formula, creating a TeX command as I did above, and then putting the TeX expression in a LaTeX document and creating a pdf-file. I suggested that particular command so that you obtain the formulae in the form you said you wanted. Don't export the notebook. Make the equation you want a TeX command, take the output as shown above, TeX the output and get a pdf-file.

Comment: Well, I have a notebook with other formulas as well. I would like to convert all in PDF not just these long fractions alone in a separate file.

Comment: Then, you have to take each formula, do what is described above, and put all the formulae in the same pdf-file. This should be very easy, but it will take some time. If you want to do it in one step, the procedure is described here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html
but I don't know how you can obtain the form of the formulae that you want.

Comment: So you mean editing pdf file? Because if you want to put formula in the same pdf file than we will need another tool for editing pdf file and that is cumbersome.

Comment: Not editing the pdf-file, just editing the LaTeX file. Instead of doing just one expression as I did above, do as many as you want in a LaTeX file, and you are done with all the expressions, create the pdf-file. We have a workshop today, if you cannot do it, leave a comment here and when I find time, I will do another example.